# The Inner join in my sql code is not working and how do i select only particular colums from the second table?

Tags: sql, oracle, import, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

```sql
SELECT "KNDNR","HZDAT"
FROM "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_CE10010_C3" AS A 
WHERE SUBSTR("HZDAT",1,4) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
INNER JOIN "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_KNA1_C3" ON 
  "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_CE10010_C3"."KNDNR" = "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_KNA1_C3"."KUNNR"
```

This is my code. Here until the inner join the code is working. **The inner join statement is not working**. Its showing error as "Command not ended properly".
I am using this to import tables into Power BI.
**And i also want to select only few columns from the 2nd table as well.**

schema name:"INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"
table1 name:"V_REPL_CE10010_C3"
table2 name:"V_REPL_KNA1_C3"
column name:"KNDNR","KNDNR"

Comment: Why are you using double quotes everywhere, and also why are you specifying the full namespace when referring to your tables?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should construct your query. `Join` first before doing any `Where` conditions.

Then use your table alias to join the columns `B.*` of your 2nd table

```
SELECT A."KNDNR",A."HZDAT", B."KNDNR"
FROM "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_CE10010_C3" AS A 
INNER JOIN "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_KNA1_C3" AS B ON  B."KNDNR" = A."KUNNR"
WHERE SUBSTR(A."HZDAT",1,4) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your joins before your `WHERE` clause and using your table alias in the `ON` condition:

```sql
SELECT "KNDNR","HZDAT"
FROM "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_CE10010_C3" AS A 
INNER JOIN "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_KNA1_C3" AS B ON A."KNDNR" = B."KUNNR"
WHERE SUBSTR("HZDAT",1,4) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is messed up in multiple ways.  Obviously, the clauses are in the incorrect order.  You should also:

- use meaningful table aliases
- eschew comparisons between strings and numbers
- qualify the column names

So:

```
SELECT rc."KNDNR", "HZDAT"
FROM "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_CE10010_C3" rc INNER JOIN
     "INFM_RBINPJDT_CSC1"."V_REPL_KNA1_C3" rk
     ON rc."KNDNR" = rk."KUNNR"
WHERE SUBSTR("HZDAT", 1, 4) = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY');
```

You should also qualify `HZDAT`, but I don't know what table/view that comes from.